# How to exactly replay a git branch history with changed commit messages?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a branch where I want to change a bunch of commit messages. I don't care about rewriting history. The branch has a lot of changes, so rebasing it on top of master is not practical (many commits have a lot of conflicts and it will take weeks to resolve it).

What I want is (given that history so far is consistent and merges were used from master) basically cherry-pick all the commits and merges that were done on the branch exactly, and in order, occasionally amending a commit message. Basically recreate it from scratch and force push.

I thought that git rebase --interactive --preserve-merges (first commit)^ would do just that; however, when that is done, it still encounters conflicts when redoing the merges. Why is that? The merges are done exactly in the same state of the branch AND from exactly the same commit (that used to be the HEAD of master), and the merge commit includes conflict resolution, so why the conflicts? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interactive rebase still has to *perform* the merges.  It can't just take the original merge's trees since (as far as it knows) you're making other changes that change the merge results.

Since you are *not* actually changing the trees, only the messages, the command that comes with git that does what you want<sup>1</sup> is `git filter-branch`.

The filter you want is the "message filter" (`--msg-filter`).  The tricky part is coming up with a filter that affects just the commit(s) you want affected.  There is no single set way to do that, but one option would be to write a shell script that checks `$GIT_COMMIT` against a set of "new" messages, something like:

```
#! /bin/sh
new_msg_dir=/absolute/path  # we don't know $cwd during a msg-filter
if [ -f "$new_msg_dir/$GIT_COMMIT" ]; then
    cat "$new_msg_dir/$GIT_COMMIT"
else
    cat
fi
```

which automates the job of replacing the stdin contents (the original message) with the file contents (from the file named by the commit-ID) if and only if there's a replacement message.

Obviously this is all untested.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, almost what you want.  Plus a lot more than you want, which makes it so much fun<sup>2</sup> to script it to do exactly what you want.

<sup>2</sup>Or some other word.

Comment: It looks like I won't be able to properly propagate and change messages on merges with this though? It appears to rewrite all master commits that came thru the merges too.

Comment: The `filter-branch` command rewrites all the commits you specify, by passing your argument to `git rev-list`.  It does two parsing passes, one to find "positive refs" (which, e.g., means that in `A..B` only `B` gets counted) and one to get commits to rewrite (which means everything output by `git rev-list A..B`).  It then applies your filter(s) to every commit selected, and when it's done, it rewrites the "positive ref" labels (and tags if you put in a `--tag-filter`). [continued in next comment]

Comment: If you're worried about changing *too many* messages, note that the proposed `--msg-filter` only changes a message if its SHA-1 ID is in the directory of "new messages".  If you're worried about changing *too few*, note that it changes *every* message of a commit that's in that directory, including merge commits.